# Is Pre-receive hooks present in GitHub Enterprise cloud version

Tags: github, hook

in GitHub Enterprise server version we have some Pre-receive hooks configured for our project to restrict few file extension commit, PR can be created from what branch to which branch etc. But not seeing this option in GitHub Enterprise cloud version.

Can anyone please confirm whether this Pre-receive hooks feature exists in GitHub Enterprise cloud version or not? If yes please guide me with navigation for it.

Wanted to reuse Pre-receive hook scripts from GitHub Enterprise server version into GitHub Enterprise cloud version after migration.

Not seeing Pre-receive hook in  GitHub Enterprise cloud version

Answer (score 2):

GitHub Enterprise Cloud, which runs on github.com, does not offer pre-receive hooks.  That's because doing so would essentially require executing arbitrary code (the pre-receive hooks specified by a user) on the file servers holding Git data, which GitHub doesn't want to do, since it would be a security risk.

In GitHub Enterprise Server, the pre-receive hooks run on an appliance which the enterprise maintains themselves, so it's assumed that the instance administrator finds the risks of executing the pre-receive hooks acceptable.

In general, many kinds of operations can be implemented as a CI job (e.g., with GitHub Actions) instead, which can be used to prevent people from merging certain files into protected branches or prevent people from merging certain branches together.  If you mark the relevant CI job as required and fail if the contents are undesirable or the base and head PR branches don't meet your standards, you can effectively prevent their inclusion in the main branch.

Comment: This assume that you are using a PR-based branching strategy like GitFlow, though, right?  Is there some workaround for trunk-based branching strategies, since it seems the more recent trend is trunk-based?

Comment: Using PRs and CI jobs before merging them is possible in many branching strategies.  We do [trunk-based development](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/) using PRs and CI jobs without a problem, and in general you want to run some sort of test (and hence run CI) before merging code so you don't merge completely broken code.

Comment: When using PR's, the thing I miss is having pushes rejected because the local master is not up to date with origin.  Even with short-lived developer branches off of trunk, there is still the potential that someone pushed code while you had your branch out.  This leads to the case where the PR could be an automatic merge, but still breaks the application.  Ideally, automated regression tests would detect this, but we are not quite there with our testing just yet.